# WiFi Module Heating Issue

Tags: heat, wifi

I salvaged an RTL8188ETV WiFi from an old tablet,

[image]

I connected usb wires and used AMS1117 3.3V Regulator, it works fine for some time but heats up and looses connectivity, Regulator is tested to be fine including all connections, it heats up with or without stock antenna, tried with a small heatsink, still stops working after some time.

What could cause it to overheat? Am I supposed to limit current myself? I really need it to work as I wanna test DIY antennas on it.

Comment: does it work in the tablet?

Comment: What do you have it (electrically) connected to, other than the power supply? Did you use the recommended capacitors on the AMS1117?

Comment: @jsotola it was working in tablet, tablet has its screen gone so not useful anymore

Comment: @SpehroPefhany my computer only, no I didn't use capacitors on AMS1117

Comment: @asim this question cannot be answered unless you show how it is connected (and exactly to what which the voltages defined).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have minimum output capacitor of 22uF tantalum or 22uF ceramic + a few ohms in series near the regulator to ensure stability. If the regulator oscillates under some load conditions it could deliver more than 3.3V. An input capacitor of 10uF or 22uF near the regulator would also be a good idea.

If the input voltage to the regulator is coming from another power supply (not in the laptop), ensure that there is not a grounding issue.

Comment: A life saver, just connected 100uf electrolytic capacitor, sending this comment from rtl8188etv connected to my wifi, before it used to get untouchably hot, now barely warm

Comment: why does it have to be tantalum or ceramic? why not electrolytic? what should be the value of the resistor? under 5 Ohms?

Comment: You could use electrolytic, but you should understand the limitations.  The output capacitor and its ESR are part of the control loop of the regulator and values that are too high or too low can cause oscillation and/or unsatisfactory transient performance.  Ceramic caps have very low ESR so unless the control loop is designed to operate with ceramics, you will probably not be stable without adding Actual Series Resistance.  Electrolytics have relatively high ESR that increases at low temperatures, potentially enough to push you out of stability.  Tantalum caps have neither of these problems.